# Unable to start the startxwin cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, xterm

I was using Cygwin download by some one in our organization and the xterm worked fine, I recently updated the xterm version, since then I lost the ability to use the xwindow/start the xserver. The bash console where I ran the startxwin shows the following and does not open the xterm window. I manually opened the xterm window and it does not open the xwindows when I ssh'd into the remote machine.

```
$ startxwin
:0" in "list" command display name "6175
xauth: (stdin):1:  bad "add" command line

Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.19.3.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 6175 2.8.0(0.309/5/3) 2017-04-01 20:47 x86_64
OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (Win64)
Package: version 1.19.3-2 built 2017-04-23

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/XWin :0 -multiwindow -auth
 /home/usrpao/.serverauth.13204

(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/usrpao/.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - RemoteSession: no
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000005
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 2560 height: 1024 depth: 32
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in                                                                                 the kernel
glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
(II) AIGLX: Testing pixelFormatIndex 1
GL_VERSION:     4.3.0 - Build 10.18.14.4280
GL_VENDOR:      Intel
GL_RENDERER:    Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_MESA_swap_control
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_SGIS_multisample
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile
(II) GLX: enabled GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
(II) 80 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
(II) 44 fbConfigs
(II) ignored pixel formats: 0 not OpenGL, 0 unknown pixel type, 36 unaccelerated
(II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 1280 512
(--) 8 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 4
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winInitMultiWindowWM - xcb_connect () returned and successfully opened the display.
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - xcb_connect() returned and successfully opened the display.
OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
Using Composite redirection
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and tracked it down to startx misbehaving.  This is what I saw:

```
$ ./startx -- :1
:1" in "list" command display name "hostname
xauth: (stdin):1:  bad "add" command line
```

The problem is with the way startx is setting its `hostname` variable.  It does not strip out the carriage return.  Later, when startx uses the `hostname` variable, the contained carriage return causes xuath "add" command to terminate prematurely and fail.

The fix for me was to strip out the carriage return.

Find where the variable `hostname` gets set in `/usr/bin/startx`, and just below there add this line:

```
hostname=$(echo $hostname | sed 's/\x0D//g')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a PATH issue. Cygwin\bin should be in the PATH before Windows\System32.

Otherwise `system32\hostname.exe` is invoked instead of `/bin/hostname`, which adds a trailing newline to the hostname.

A possible workaround is to invoke `/bin/hostname` instead of just `hostname`:

```
sed -i s/\`hostname/\`\\/bin\\/hostname/ /usr/bin/startx /usr/bin/startxwin
```

... but you'll face other issues until you put Cygwin at the beginning of the PATH (though then you might face yet other issues, so there's no ideal solution).